# Full Calendar loads events

Tags: events, fullcalendar, reload, dropdown

Good morning,
I use a dropdown to select what events' user I have to display in the calendar. The events are loaded from database to a file JsonEvents.txt.
When I change the user from the dropdown and I click the custom button to display new events, the calendar doesn't load the events. Only if I wait for some second and then click the button, in this case the calendar show the corrects events. What is the problem? Why the calendar immediately doesn't show new events? Thanks in advance.

This is the javascript code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
          $(document).ready(function() {              
              var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({ 
                lang: 'it',
                customButtons: {
                    myCustomButton: {
                        text: 'Visualizza',
                        click: function() {

                            $("#calendar").fullCalendar('refetchEvents');                               

                        }
                    }
                },
                header: { 
                  left: 'prev,next today myCustomButton',
                  center: 'title',  
                  right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },              
                lazyFetching: false,
                selectable: true,               
               select: function(start, end, allDay) {
                    var title = prompt('Nome evento:');                 
                    if (title) { 
                        if(end.hasTime()){  
                            var st = moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
                            var en = moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
                            createEvent(title,st,en,false);                         
                            calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');                      
                        }
                        else{
                            var st = moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD');    
                            createEvent(title,st,'',true);                          
                            calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');                      
                        }
                    }
                },
                editable: true,
                eventClick: function(event, element) {
                    $('#finestra').dialog({
                        modal: true,
                        buttons: {
                            "Si": function() {                              
                                deleteEvent(event.id);      
                                calendar.fullCalendar( 'removeEvents' , event.id);
                                $( this ).dialog( "close" );                                
                            },
                            "No": function(){
                                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                                var title = prompt('Nome evento:',event.title);
                                event.title = title;    
                                updateEvent(event.id,event.title,'','');
                                calendar.fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);                       
                            }
                         }
                     });            
                },  
                eventResize: function (event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, revertFunc) {
                    if (confirm("Confermi di modificare l'orario dell'evento?")) {
                        var st = moment(event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
                        var en = moment(event.end).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
                        updateEvent(event.id, event.title, st, en );
                    }
                    else {
                        revertFunc();
                    }
                },
                eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
                    if (confirm("Confermi di modificare la data dell'evento?")) {
                        var st = moment(event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
                        var en = moment(event.end).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
                        updateEvent(event.id, event.title, st, en );
                    }
                    else {
                        revertFunc();
                    }
                },
                events: {
                    url: "JsonEvents.txt",                  
                }   

              });  

            }); 
    </script>
```

The dropdown is created in jsp code:

```
<form action="../AgendaServlet" method="post"  id="frm_age" >

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td  class="row">
                    <span class="small_label">Select user</span>
                </td><td  class="row  s230" align="right">  
                    <select class="custom-select s230" id="specialista" name="specialista" onchange="viewEvents()">
                    <% list = (List<KeyValueString>) session.getAttribute(Def.list_specialisti);
                            if (list != null) {
                                for (KeyValueString kv : list) {    %>
                                     <option value="<%=kv.getKey()  %>" ><%=kv.getValue() %></option>                                    
                        <%  } 
                            } %>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div id='calendar'></div>

    </form>
```

The jsp code works fine. The problem I think is in the javascript code.

Comment: there's not enough info here - you need to post your actual code so we can see what's happening, and also check your browser console and network tab and report here any errors that you see. Based only on your description there could be lots of reasons. But also, why do you load the data from the database into a text file first? Why not just load them directly from the database into the calendar?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to post the code.

Comment: edit your question, don't post it as an answer (because it's not the answer) :-)

Comment: You said: "When I change the user from the dropdown and I click the custom button to display new events...". Where is the mentioned dropdown in your code?

Comment: @Nerina what is the size of your events? I mean is it too large?Can you post your event file ? Because from what I see , you set lazy fetching to false.So ,imo this might be the issue if your events size is large and if the date range of events are far.

Comment: @Nerina you need to show the "ViewEvents" function. Just the markup of the select is insufficient. We need to see what happens when the dropdown changes.

Comment: Thank you all. I resolved the problem. I changed the url of the events from   "JsonEvents.txt" directly to the servlet. It works very well. I don't need to create a txt file.

Comment: @Nerina I told you that in the very first comment...